# Laptop wireless not working following Linux install

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, acpi

I have an HP ProBook 4740s which came installed with Windows 7. I recently installed Linux Mint 17.2 on the laptop. Im not dual booting, the laptop now only has Mint on it.

Since the installation, the physical wireless button on the laptop no longer works. It constantly has a yellow light on it (ie: disabled). Nothing happens when I press the button, it just stays yellow.

Im not sure if this is a software/linux/driver issue, but it started happening when I installed Mint. I use to be able to press the button while the laptop was booting up (or at any time) and the wireless light would switch to blue (ie: enabled). That is no longer possible.

I looked in the bios but couldn't see anything that looked like it could be causing the problem (although I don't know exactly what to look for).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Besides the LED functionality: Does it actually switch the WLAN on/off? Most likely it is a driver issue (I at least used to have a similar problem - LED always off, functionality of switch as expected). Try another driver or get one from the manufacturers homepage. For listing your hardware, use `lshw` in a terminal.

Comment: HPs today are mostly Linux-compatible, so there should be a driver for your WiFi card available. Perhaps a site like http://www.linux-on-laptops.com or directly some Mint user forum is your best bet. If you solve your problem, please do add an answer (and accept it) to close the question here.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. Pressing the wireless button enables the wifi in the sense that if I right click the connections icon in the task panel, 'Enable Wifi' will be checked. However the wifi doesn't work. If I open up driver manager, it doesn't say anything about my wireless. Im not sure how else to check or install drivers since it doesn't say anything about my wireless.